# Is it possible to download googleVis plots from R?

Tags: r, shiny

Follow up from :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/u7gwXc8_vyY

I have the exact same R Shiny structured program as the user in the post, except I am using the googleVis Shiny package for my plots. For example, here is a plot of a gVis table:

```
 output$gvisTable <- renderGvis( {
    if (is.null(dataset))
      return(NULL)


    gvisTable(dataset)



  })
```

EDIT:

My code to save ggplots:

```
server.R
    name <- paste0(input$filename, ".png")
        print(p)
        if(input$savePlot) {
          ggsave(name, p, type="cairo-png")
        }
```

ui.R (in sidePanel)

```
wellPanel(
                       textInput('filename', "Filename"),
                       checkboxInput('savePlot', "Check to save")  
                     )
```

This is what I am using to try to save gVis plots:

```
name <- paste0(input$filename, ".png")
    if(input$savePlot) {
      png(name, *INPUT GVIS PLOT HERE*, type="cairo-png")
      dev.off()
    }
```

This does not work: I get the error: 'non-numeric argument to binary operator'

I can't find a way to allow the user to download a gVis plot. I can't use the method in the linked post because you cannot 'print' a gVis plot.

Also, the files are locally saved to my R working directory, but I plan to upload this app to the web. Where would the files be saved for the user? Ideas?

Comment: I had no problems printing a googleVis chart. It's not being displayed in R;  it's in your browser window. So this should have the tag of whatever unstated browser and OS you are using.

Comment: I am running on Windows 7 on a Chrome browser.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code I use to save ggplots  and the error I get for gvis saves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no `png` method documented for gvis objects.

There are two ways to "print" documented in the help page linked from the googleVis main Index page for `print.gvis`. The default method (when the `tag` is NULL or "html") is to send a Java script page to your browser. The other (when you set `tag="chart"` is to construct an html file with the name you give it. I suppose you could arrange something with `system` commands sent to a running instance of a particular browser, but for that you should use different SO tags so that you attract the interest of people using the same software as you. (I'm using a Mac with Firefox and having no difficulties seeing the "printed" output.) If you plan to "upload it to the web", then you need to have a server. Is my impression this is a bit new for you correct?

```
print(GTM, tag="chart", file="test.html")  
#created in my working directory
```